# Powershell: IIS Site names into an array

Tags: arrays, powershell, authentication, iis, anonymous

I'm looking to populate an array with the site names from IIS. My plan was to use this array/loop through it, to then set the Anonymous Authentication for each site, to Application pool identity, by settings the username to blank.

`Set-Webconfigurationproperty –filter /system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication  “IIS:\Sites\[array]” –name username –value “”`

Bit stuck on how to get the names into an arry though.  Any smart way of getting the name field from `gci iis:\sites` maybe?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $sites = @((gci iis:\sites).Name)

Comment: Wow, that was easy!  :)

Thanks David!